# 220£ tournament

Tags: tournament

I've been playing last weekend a 25k guaranteed  buy in 220£.
I get a entry by satellite of 30£.
Initial chips 25k

My stack 27k
CO 33k

On the first level 50/100. I was very quiet, at this point I didn't want to play big pots, no bluffs I didn't want troubles.
After 30 min I was in sb with KK,  UTG+1 open raise 300 and CO re raise 875, at this point I was thinking if I call or make a 4bet,( I've won two hands at the same guy on CO before, 1. He opened preflop and 3bet he fold 2. Post flop in a hand he opened preflop)
I've decided to make a 4 bet to 2000, UTG+1 fold and CO wad thinking about 2 min and he did a 5bet of to 15000k.
At this point I was thinking on the possibility of he has AA.
But after  I dont think AA play like this, and is only hand can win me  to lot of hands I go ahead.
I was thinking to fold my KK because I didn't want to play a big pot on the first level but I couldn't no take the opportunity of double up early.I made all in and he pay me asking for a reentry, he showed AQ and he hit me the A on turn and bye bye tournament for me.
My question is, 
Do you think I have to fold to reduce the risk on the first level?
Even knowing the guy can have lot of pairs worse than me?
What do you guys play in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You should only fold KK against opponents that you know very well and have an excellent read on, preferrably a nit that would only ever show such strength with AA but not as much with weaker pairs such as JJ,QQ,KK. This will usually never happened. Daniel Ngeranu once said that he has folded KK twice to a pre-flop all in. Once the opponent had AA and once the opponent had QQ.

You're going to be ahead most of the time with KK and even when you happen to turn into the rare aces, you can always draw them out.

AA can lose against 72, you'd have to argue folding AA if you'd even consider folding KK. KK has too much value to fold.

This is from a theoretical standpoint. If you absolutely can not afford to lose, however, you can argue the fold if you're fine with making that -EV move in order to only get into small pots and win with the nuts, you should reconsider whether you should be playing then in the first place or not. It's going to be almost impossible to get far in a big tournament without taking advantage of such goldmine spots which will make you win 70% of the time.

There can be made a theoretical [argument](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/when-to-fold-aa-pre-flop) for folding strong hands such as AA pre-flop but it's rare and very situational.

Answer (score 0):

If you 4 bet that small there you're effectively playing your hand face up. I would have made it maybe 5x the initial raise to about 3000-4000.

I think given the fact you "play it safe" that your opponents could have sensed that they may have some fear equity in a situation.

You could make the case that the other player is a nit, and that he was never folding whatever you did.

Comment: I think that 4 bet was to get a fold?

Comment: Still though raising larger would generally get a fold no? its only really 2.5x the 3 bet. It should be 5x or 6x.

Comment: So you think hero on KK wanted a fold?

Comment: I think he wanted to Iso which he did, but he induced a massive raise from the villain with such a small 3 Bet. I mean its not bad getting in there, the only logistical concern is that they're facing a decision for a significant amount of their chips early on in the tournament.

Comment: Yes its about the early decision to play all my chips on the first level of the tournament..

Comment: The only change I'd make would be to 4bet bigger, you're line was okay. It does happen sometimes when the opponent binks an Ace, but you'll probably receive a rub of good variance to balance this out. If you're folding KK there you're essentially saying that all that your opponent can ever have there is aces, which would be a terrible play. And for him to 5xbet to 15000 is extremely unlikely for aces to do. You're play was fine, maybe be less results orientated in this instance and be confident that you got it in good, and were unlucky to be beaten.

Answer (score -1):

You have to bet KK.  You are only facing AA 1 every 220 hands. He could be playing a lot of pairs you dominate. Ax you are still ahead 7:3.  Against the range 77+, AJs+, and AQo+ you are 7:3.  Against that range even QQ is 3:2.

I read it again and you were behind a raise and a re-raise and you were deep stacked.  KK is the second best hand but it has blockers on AK and KK. If they are tight then I think you can fold here. If you know they will play AQo then it is a clear call. I agree it is a push fold as you would be calling off half your stack.

What I don't get is AQ re-reraise?  You would be pot committed so they should just call or push.  Did they really think AQ was good after you 3 bet.  They should have just called in position hand hoped for a pair on the flop.

Comment: He has aces 1 in 220 hands if you pick a random hand. In this spot his range is obviously tighter and he will show up with aces more frequently

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans I think we can assume she is not playing a random hand here.   I even covered a range and odds for that range.

Comment: I totally agree. Yet your answer states "You are only facing AA 1 in 220 hands."

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans I think people get that means the odd of AA but I am glad you cleared that up for them.